# .Net Socket (UDP) Sending, Receiving and Scheduling

Tags: c#, sockets, udp

I am currently on a personal project for learning purposes. I want to make a connection over UDP, for application such as games. Each datagram sent has a specific header that indicates which "logic" channel it belongs to - for example, channel 0 is just like UDP with the extra header overhead, and channel 1 uses more headers to bring some extra reliability. The channels objective is to "automatically" separate messages into logic groups, up to a specific amount.

In my current code, there is a simple loop in a separate thread that handles sending and receiving:

```
// This is pseudo code
public void Tick() {
    if(Socket.Poll) {
        do {
            ReadMessage();
        } while(Socket.Available > 0)
    }

    SendQueuedOutgoingMessages();
}
```

Though this works on an ideal world, I have this feeling that this logic fails when there are too many incoming or outgoing messages. Is it possible to use the same socket to simultaneously send and receive messages (i.e send and receive are asynchronous or in different threads)? Even if it is possible, would it be better if I simply used two or more UDP sockets (or mix TCP and UDP sockets, if I need reliability), having specially maintainability in mind?

The most direct alternative I can think around this would be to use a scheduling algorithm to control how many messages to read and send, by means of queue sizes or other factors, but this feels poor and inflexible in this situation.

Edit: Adding more information about the code.

The Tick() method is set to be called a specific amount of times per second if it immediately returns. For example, 30 times per second if no new in or out messages exists, and less if it needs some time to send or receive data. I've used blocking ReceiveFrom and SendTo methods as to avoid busy waiting or calls such as Sleep(0).

Though I immediately treat incoming messages, I use an outgoing messages queue to help with the channels idea - each channel has its own priority down to 'no priority', affecting its bandwidth share over time in smooth and busy moments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether or not using 2 sockets for receiving and sending separately, or just a single one depends on the situation. If you are going to send a lot of messages, and even if you are on a dedicated thread, the socket might block if the outgoing queue that is used by the socket becomes full.

There are several solutions to this problem. Using 2 sockets and 2 distinct threads is one of them, using select in combination with asynchronous sockets is another. The point is that you don't want to stop receiving just because a send might block.

Each of these possible solutions have their own complexity.

The select api is meant to check if for a certain socket there is something to receive, but you can also use it to detect if a socket becomes writable again. You need a socket option to put the socket in non blocking state and you need to check for E_WOULDBLOCK return codes with each send. If so the send has failed and you have to queue the message yourself.

You don't really send and receive at the same time, it is sequentially. You use select to check if a socket is writable and readible by using 2 bitmasks manipulated with the fd_set api. You can use select even on multiple sockets at once. Then if select, which is a blocking call, returns, you can check each individual bit to check what actions needs to be performed.

The reason why a send can block, if a socket is not put in nonblocking state is that the output queue of the socket can be full. If the socket is blocking, it would simply wait for the queue to become ready again. But during that wait, you cannot receive anything on that same socket. This is the very reason why you need non blocking sockets and the select api, in combination with some kind of queueing mechanism yourself.

Comment: By 'select' you mean detecting whenever there is something to send/receive, and then executing the related asynchronous operation as soon as possible? That being the case, is it correct to assume that a Socket can asynchronously execute a Send and a Receive operation at the same time?

Comment: not at the same time, but you check if it is possible to actually send something before doing the send, and you check if there is anything to receive as well. As such, you are never blocked. Suppose you do a send and the queue is full, you would block on the send, and as long as the queue is full, you will not receive, even though there might be somehting to receive. Network programming is really an advanced topic  and the code becomes complicated easily.

Comment: I've accepted this answer. It'd be nice if you could add your comment to the answer, as it is related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply the standard read loop setup?

```
while (true)
    ReadMessage();
```

There is no scheduling or throttling necessary. It is not necessary to know whether a packet is ready or not.

You can read and write simultaneously on the same UDP socket.

There is no need for an outgoing queue, either. Just send.

Comment: What you mean is to use two different threads, one only for sending and other only for receiving?

Comment: That would be a good way to do it. You also can use async IO but I see no evidence whatsoever that you need that. Also note that select and poll are obsolete programming models, at least in the .NET world.

Comment: Didn't know that (and it seems like Poll feeds the GC). Actually, that's quite interesting.